# Android Как активировать ночной режим

Tags: android, google-maps, android-themes

Реализую в приложении "ночной" режим.
Как заставить Google maps API v2 работать в "Дарк" режиме?

Comment: Был тут ранее такой вопрос. night mode в api гугла нету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Google Maps насколько я знаю нет предустановленого ночного режима.
То что вы видите используя Google Maps достигается установкой стилей карты с указанием какие элементы какими цветами закрашивать.

вот стили для ночного режима в формате json

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#242f3e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "lightness": -80
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#746855"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#d59563"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#d59563"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#263c3f"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#6b9a76"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#2b3544"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9ca5b3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#38414e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212a37"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#746855"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1f2835"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f3d19c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#38414e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212a37"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#2f3948"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#d59563"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#17263c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#515c6d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "lightness": -20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Вам необходимо положить их в ресурсы(/res/raw/style_json.json) и вызвать GoogleMap.setMapStyle()

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json));
```

Есть подробная инструкция по адресу:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling